# create a y-m-d.json file in the respective directory (year/month) by iterating multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, file-put-contents

**try to create or update a json file based on the processed data.**

first I arrange the contents using `assamble()` and create a multidimensional array:

```php
$logfile_accepted_array = [
    "AAAA 2022 12 23 21:37:56 dc:16:b2:4c:d2:e6",
    "BBB 2023 01 12 02:08:23 f0:8a:76:16:57:e8",
    "BBB 2023 02 19 17:34:33 a0:c9:a0:b6:79:3c",
    "AAAA 2023 02 23 12:21:09 f0:8a:76:16:57:e8",
    "AAAA 2023 02 23 18:15:10 f0:8a:76:16:57:e8",
    "CCCCC 2023 03 19 17:07:26 f0:8a:76:16:57:e8",
    "QQQ 2023 04 01 00:00:03 a0:c9:a0:b6:79:3c"
];

// Make directory and subdirectories ...
function dirMaker($directory, $sub_directory, $sub_sub_directory)
{
    if (!is_dir($directory . $sub_directory . $sub_sub_directory)) {
        mkdir(
            $directory . $sub_directory . $sub_sub_directory,
            0777,
            true
            // If true, then any parent directories 
            // to the directory specified will also be created, 
            // with the same permissions.
        );
    }
}

$root = 'archive/';
```

assemble data

```php
function assemble($logfile_accepted_array)
{
    global $dailyData;

    # Get the colors for the zone 
    $getColors = file_get_contents('zones.json');
    $zoneColor = json_decode($getColors, true);
    // Group rows of data by column value then store nested data, first and last occurrences, and counts within each group
    foreach ($logfile_accepted_array as $row) {
        [$group, $date_year, $date_month_numeric, $day_digits, $time, $id] = explode(' ', $row);
        $result[$date_year][$date_month_numeric][$day_digits][$group]['user'][$id][] = $time;
    }

    $dailyData = $result;
}
assemble($logfile_accepted_array);
```

result

```php
array (
  2022 => 
  array (
    12 => 
    array (
      23 => 
      array (
        'AAAA' => 
        array (
          'user' => 
          array (
            'dc:16:b2:4c:d2:e6' => 
            array (
              0 => '21:37:56',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2023 => 
  array (
    '01' => 
    array (
      12 => 
      array (
        'BBB' => 
        array (
          'user' => 
          array (
            'f0:8a:76:16:57:e8' => 
            array (
              0 => '02:08:23',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
/...
```

And now comes the big challenge:

- create a y-m-d.json file in the respective directory (year/month) by iterating multidimensional array

In json files the year, month and day should not be omitted. But put in the correct year/month directory with which json filenames (y-m-d.json) are written.

```php
function archiveJSON($logfile_accepted_array, $root, $dailyData)
{
    foreach ($logfile_accepted_array as $year_group) {
        [$group, $date_year, $date_month_numeric, $day_digits, $time, $id] = explode(' ', $year_group);
        $yearDir[$group][] = $date_year;
        $monthDir[$group][] = $date_month_numeric;
        $dayDir[$group][] = $day_digits;
        $user_id[$group][] = $id;
        $loged_time[$group][] = $time;

        dirMaker($root, $date_year . '/', $date_month_numeric . '/');
        $path = $root . $date_year . '/' . $date_month_numeric . '/';
        $json_file = $date_year . '-' . $date_month_numeric . '-' . $day_digits . '.json';

        if (!file_exists($path . $json_file)) {
            // Create a new json file in current date directory
            // and write data
            fopen($path . $json_file, 'w');
            file_put_contents($path . $json_file, json_encode($dailyData[$date_year][$date_month_numeric][$day_digits], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
        } else {
            # Existing Data
            $existing_json_file = file_get_contents($path . $json_file);
            $existing_array = json_decode($existing_json_file, true);

            foreach ($dailyData as $letter => $set) {
                if (!isset($existing_array[$letter])) {
                    $existing_array[$letter] = $set;
                } else {
                    $existing_array[$letter]['user'] = array_merge_recursive(
                        $existing_array[$letter]['user'],
                        $set['user']
                    );
                }
            }
            // update file
            file_put_contents($path . $json_file, json_encode($dailyData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
        }
    }
}
archiveJSON($logfile_accepted_array, $root, $dailyData);
```

yes! if the directories (year/month) do not exist, they will be created `if (!file_exists($path . $json_file))`:

2022/12, 2023/1,2,3,4 and the json files with the right names (Y-m-d.json) in the right directory too.

expected json file content in 2023/02/2023-02-19.json:

```json
{
    "BBB": {
        "user": {
            "a0:c9:a0:b6:79:3c": [
                "17:34:33"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

expected json file content in 2023/02/2023-02-23.json:

```json
{
    "AAAA": {
        "user": {
            "f0:8a:76:16:57:e8": ["12:21:09", "18:15:10"]
        }
    }
}
```

**for the 1st i'm stuck here:**

but if one of the letters has 2 entries on the same date as in this example: `AAAA 2023 02 23 12:21:09 ...` and `AAAA 2023 02 23 18:15:10 ...` then the **2023-02-23.json** file all year entries written - unexpected json file content in 2023/02/2023-02-23.json:

```json
{
    "2022": {
        "12": {
            "23": {
                "AAAA": {
                    "user": {
                        "dc:16:b2:4c:d2:e6": [
                            "21:37:56"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "2023": {
        "01": {
            "12": {
                "BBB": {
                    "user": {
                        "f0:8a:76:16:57:e8": [
                            "02:08:23"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "02": {
            "19": {
                "BBB": {
                    "user": {
                        "a0:c9:a0:b6:79:3c": [
                            "17:34:33"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "23": {
                "AAAA": {
                    "user": {
                        "f0:8a:76:16:57:e8": [
                            "12:21:09",
                            "18:15:10"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "03": {
            "19": {
                "CCCCC": {
                    "user": {
                        "f0:8a:76:16:57:e8": [
                            "17:07:26"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "04": {
            "01": {
                "QQQ": {
                    "user": {
                        "a0:c9:a0:b6:79:3c": [
                            "00:00:03"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

else: if there are json data in the right directory with the right files, then complete them with the new entries:

**secondly, I'm stuck here as well:**

as above, all entries are written in each of the json files.

I would have to put `$dailyData[$date_year][$date_month_numeric][$day_digits]` in the right place. Or am I misunderstanding something?

i try many hours around. I spin around in circles.

Please don't be too harsh with me, because I'm an ambitious beginner and my head is getting tired.

Comment: About your first problem: You have described what you end up with. Can you provide a sample about what you would expect to end up with?

Comment: I thought my explanation was clear. I'm trying to improve the description. what exactly is incomprehensible here?

Comment: @LajosArpad, now: better explained and result I expect. i hope this more clearly

Comment: Are the files already existent when you test? If they are: can you test without such files to see how new files would be created?

Comment: Hello, I was ill and am well again. sorry if i'm raging late. I'm looking at it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've presented a lot of code -- which I am finding difficult to read on my phone, but I believe your process is:

1. Parse an array of lines and populate a multi-level hierarchical array
2. Iterate the unique first 3 levels of the data structure, then
3. Ensure that directories exist to accommodate the top three levels, then
4. Access, decode, and recursively merge preexisting data in a given file (if it exists), then
5. Save the new file contents.

Untested Suggested Code:

```
$fileLines = [
    "AAAA 2022 12 23 21:37:56 dc:16:b2:4c:d2:e6",
    "BBB 2023 01 12 02:08:23 f0:8a:76:16:57:e8",
    "BBB 2023 02 19 17:34:33 a0:c9:a0:b6:79:3c",
    "AAAA 2023 02 23 12:21:09 f0:8a:76:16:57:e8",
    "AAAA 2023 02 23 18:15:10 f0:8a:76:16:57:e8",
    "CCCCC 2023 03 19 17:07:26 f0:8a:76:16:57:e8",
    "QQQ 2023 04 01 00:00:03 a0:c9:a0:b6:79:3c"
];

$result = [];
foreach ($fileLines as $line) {
    [$group, $yyyy, $mm, $dd, $His, $id] = explode(' ', $line);
    $result[$yyyy][$mm][$dd][$group]['user'][$id][] = $His;
}

foreach ($result as $y => $months) {
    foreach ($months as $m => $days) {
        foreach ($days as $d => $groups) {
            $path = "$root/$y/$m";
            $filepath = "$path/$y-$m-$d.json";
            if (!file_exists($path)) {
                mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                $newContent = $groups;
            } elseif (!file_exists($filepath)) {
                $newContent = $groups;
            } else {
                $newContent = array_merge_recursive(
                    json_decode(file_get_contents($filepath), true),
                    $groups
                );
            }
            file_put_contents(
                $filepath,
                json_encode($newContent, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your support. I implemented your suggestion and realized that: 
for example if the fileLines haven't changed: the existing time is added again.
Expected: if the same prime time exists, then ignore - just add new ones:
here the actual result: ```php {"QQQ": {"user": {"a0:c9:a0:b6:79:3c": ["00:00:03","00:00:03"]}}}``` I'm trying around, can't find a solution

Comment: Might I recommend that you make the entire data path "associative"? `$result[$yyyy][$mm][$dd][$group]['user'][$id][$His] = $His;`? This way, you can enjoy the elegance of `array_replace_recursive()`. https://3v4l.org/6qVeu  Alternatively, if you MUST have indexes in the lowest level, you could write more nested loops and call `array_unique()` after merging each bottom level -- not as elegant.

Comment: ...the alternative/inelegant approach: https://3v4l.org/kZV1k

Comment: the elegant variant, write this ```[21:37:56] => 21:37:56``` but indexing would be ```[0] => 21:37:56``` better? how can i handle with $oldContent? I didn't quite get it. https://3v4l.org/tBeO4#v8.2.3

Comment: If you want to try my first way, you'd need to adjust the old content already in files (to also be fully associative).  If that is too much work, use the second way.

Comment: I think I made it: https://3v4l.org/BE8uL#v8.2.3

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that

```
file_put_contents($path . $json_file, json_encode($dailyData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

prints the whole JSON. You need to refer to the correct path to your data in the `else` branch as well as you did in the `if` branch.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I didn't misunderstand your point.

If you want the `2023/02/2023-02-23.json` file contains data like this:

```json
{
    "AAAA": {
        "user": {
            "f0:8a:76:16:57:e8": [
                "12:21:09",
                "18:15:10"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

then change these lines:

```php
foreach ($dailyData as $letter => $set) {
    if (!isset($existing_array[$letter])) {
        $existing_array[$letter] = $set;
    } else {
        $existing_array[$letter]['user'] = array_merge_recursive(
            $existing_array[$letter]['user'],
            $set['user']
        );
    }
}
// update file
file_put_contents($path . $json_file, json_encode($dailyData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

to:

```php
foreach ($dailyData as $letter => $set) {
    if (isset($existing_array[$letter])) {
        $existing_array[$letter]['user'] = array_merge_recursive(
            $existing_array[$letter]['user'],
            $set['user']
        );
    }
}
// update file
file_put_contents($path . $json_file, json_encode($existing_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

---

**OR**

if you want the `2023/02/2023-02-23.json` file contains data like this:

```json
unexpected json file content in 2023-02-23.json
```

then change these lines:

```php
...
} else {
    # Existing Data
    $existing_json_file = file_get_contents($path . $json_file);
    $existing_array = json_decode($existing_json_file, true);

    foreach ($dailyData as $letter => $set) {
        if (!isset($existing_array[$letter])) {
            $existing_array[$letter] = $set;
        } else {
            $existing_array[$letter]['user'] = array_merge_recursive(
                $existing_array[$letter]['user'],
                $set['user']
            );
        }
    }
    // update file
    file_put_contents($path . $json_file, json_encode($dailyData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

to:

```php
...
} else {
    // update file
    file_put_contents($path . $json_file, 'unexpected json file content in ' . $json_file);
}
```